# Finding how many times a digit is in a number

Tags: python

This is currently what I'm at, I'm stuck with how to find how many times the digit was in the number, using the for loop. If anyone has any basic ideas, I'm new to python, so I'm not too knowledgeable about this language.

```
#Assignment 6

#Start out with print instructions
print """
This program will take a Number and Digit that you enter.
It will then find the number of times the digit is in your number.
Afterwards, this program will multiply your number by your digit.
"""

#Get the user's number

number = raw_input("Enter a number: ")

#Use a while loop to make sure the number is valid

while (number == ""):
    print "You have entered an invalid number."
    number = raw_input("Enter another number: ")

#Get the digit

digit = raw_input("Enter a digit between 0-9: ")

#Use a while loop to make sure the digit is valid

while (int(digit) > 9):
    print "You have entered an invalid digit."
    digit = raw_input("Enter a digit between 0-9: ")

#Set the count to 0
count = 0

#Show the user their number and digit

print "Your number is:", number, "And your digit is:", digit

#Use the for loop to determine how many times the digit is in the number

for d in number:
    if d == digit
        count +=1
    else
        count +=0
print d, count
```

Comment: the 'count += 0' part is pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically invalid in its current stage,

```
if d == digit
    count +=1
else
    count +=0
```

is missing colons:

```
if d == digit:
    count +=1
else:
    count +=0 # or just pass, or better, skip the whole else tree
```

Apart from that, it works, although you should catch the errors that occur when the first (or second) input is, say, `a`.

You haven't yet solved this sub-assignment:

> Afterwards, this program will multiply your number by your digit.

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) will be very helpful in finding out how to multiply numbers.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that simple error, when I saw the line, thought it was something wrong with my syntax. THANK YOU! And for validating the inputs to make sure their not, say letters or strings, is there a way to express that with a boolean term, using the not function?

Comment: @user1010007 Glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark it as such. Usually, you don't explicitely validate in Python. Instead, just catch the exceptions. Again, the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) should explain the necessary concepts in detail.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> '123123123123111'.count('3')
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your user's inputs as strings and iterate through the characters of the string like so:

```
number = "12423543534543"
digit = "3"
```

You might want to consider putting some of this in a method instead of inline.

```
count = 0

for d in number:
  if d == digit:
    count += 1

print matched
```

Comment: Huh? That's exactly what he is already doing in the last lines.

Comment: he re-wrote the question mid-way through my answer :)